# The probability to get a given word in a PRG

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

Why is the probability to get a fixed given word ina PRG which maps $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\{0,1\}^{2n}$ equal to
$$\frac{2^n}{2^{2n}}$$ While the probability to choose 2n bit uniformly is $$\frac{1}{2^{2n}}?$$

what is the probability to geta given word in a PRG which maps $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\{0,1\}^{n+1}$  ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please make your question clearer?

Comment: I have done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean to ask: Why does a $2n$-bit value chosen uniformly at random only have a $\frac{2^n}{2^{2n}}$ chance of being the hash (PRG output) of some $n$-bit seed?

That would be because of two details:

(1.) The output of the hash is uniformly distributed, so all outputs have $\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$ probability.

(2.) There are only $2^n$ possible outputs.

Leading us to:
$$\left(\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\right)\cdot2^n=\frac{2^n}{2^{2n}} = \frac{1}{2^n}$$

So in the case with $2^{n+1}$ possible outputs, we get:
$$\left(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\cdot2^n=\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: How is it makes sense that I can only choose between 2 strings in the n+1 bit prg?                                               Are thses big probability differences   show that this prg is not indistinguishable  from choosing uniformly?